# Determine if GPS location is within city limits?

Tags: gps, location, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I want to be able to determine if a GPS location is in an inhabited or uninhabited zone.

I have tried several reverse geocoding API like Nominatim, but failed to get good results. It always returns the nearest possible address, even when I selected a location in the middle of a forest.

Is there any way to determine this with reasonable accuracy? Are there any databases or web services for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to calculate that youself, then the interesting things start:

The information whether or not a region is inhabited is stored in digital maps in layer "`Land_Use`". There are values for Forest, Water, Industry, Cemetary, etc.

You would have to import these Land_use polygons into a special DB (`PostGres`).
Such a spatial DB provides fast geo indizeds for searching only the relevant polygons.

Some countries may also fit in main memory, but then you need some kind of geo spatial index, like `Quad-Tree` or `k-d tree` to store the polygons.

Once you have imported the polygons, it is a simple "point in polygon" query, or "polygons within radius r". The typoe of th epolygon denotes the land use.

OpenStreetMap provides these polygons for free.

Otherwise you have to buy them from `TomTom` or probably NavTeq (`Nokia Maps`). But this makes only sense for major companies.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Nominatim, you're getting the coordinates of the nearest address back in the reply.

Since [the distance between two coordinates can be calculated](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), you can just use that to calculate the distance to the closest address found, and from that figure out if you're close to populated areas or not.

Comment: really great idea, this just leaves the problem of determining how far from an populated area you will have to be in order to be considered an uninhabited zone; this will prove difficult because city vary much in size.

Comment: @RexLakio One idea is to try to move a couple of hundred yards and search the closest address from there. If it doesn't change, it's a decent bet that it's not very densely populated.

Comment: Well yes, but when you search in Google Maps for a city, the EXACT city region and boundaries will be selected in a red color. I would of loved to have access to the exact boundaries, like Google apparently has. I now see that reverse geocoding was not made for this. I be looking for alternatives.